# How would I migrate to a new process in C?

Tags: c, winapi, process

this is a pretty complicated procedure so please bear with me!
The concept is straight forward anyway:

I have a C program that generates a batch file according to user input and executes it. In all cases, the batch file opens up a new terminal. I want my program to execute set commands through the new terminal.

I'm 99% positive I would need to use the Win32 API for this and am perfectly fine with taking on that challenge, but I would just like a little nudge in the right direction.

Any suggestions on how one would go about designing such a program?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: If your program is generating the batch file, why does it also need to feed data to standard input? Can't it just put it straight in the batch file?

Comment: No. The commands need to be executed through the new terminal.

Comment: I think you're confused.  You should happily be able to code your commands into a batch file and launch the batch file in a new process.    Executing a batch file does run them in the new terminal anyway, you'd just be slowing the process down.

Comment: I'm really only giving a small piece of the larger picture; the batch file will, of course, open a new terminal, but it will also spawn a terminal after *that*. And it's this final terminal that needs to take my input. Yes, it doesn't make that much sense lol but I truly do need it to operate like that. Or is this what you're saying and I really am confused?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `CreateProcess()` to start your batch script, you can specify custom pipes created with `CreatePipe()` for standard input and standard output. This will allow your application to control the application by sending any commands over the pipe.

If you only specify the standard input pipe, then the output will still be sent to its own console window.

Comment: Thank you this looks very promising. I'll see what develops.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to SendMessage(WM_CHAR) to the new console window, however it is not an error proof.

The proper way is to CreateProcess() with STARTF_USESTDHANDLES flag. See an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5531/Redirecting-an-arbitrary-Console-s-Input-Output)